# arulesViz "graph" plot doesn't show the connections

Tags: r, arules

I'm using the arulesViz library to plot some graphs about recommendation systems.
I have some rules and I want to plot them in a graph plot.

```
plot(regras, method = "graph", control = list(type = "itens"))
```

This is what I got: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in arulesViz. However, there is a workaround.

Since you do not provide any data that can be used as an example, I will use a variation of the example from the documentation. Just using the basic plot shows no links like in your question.

```
data(Groceries)
rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(support=0.002, confidence=0.8))
plot(rules, method="graph")
```

[image: Graph with no links]

However, if you set `alpha=1` the links will display.

```
plot(rules, method="graph",  alpha = 1)
```

[image: Graph with links]